# Android SearchView widget does not work

Tags: android, search, android-intent, android-activity

I have a problem getting the searchview in the actionbar working...

The issue is, that my app shows the searchview but when I attempt to search
nothing happens.

Here is the SearchActivity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements SearchListFragment.OnCardSelectedListener
{
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private static final String idLanguage = "1";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Check that the activity is using the layout version with
        // the fragment_container FrameLayout
        if (findViewById(R.id.body_fragment) != null)
        {
            // However, if we're being restored from a previous state,
            // then we don't need to do anything and should return or else
            // we could end up with overlapping fragments.
            if (savedInstanceState != null)
            {
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu)
    {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager
                .getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);            

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}
```

Here is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="eu.prindl.magiccardmarket"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="20" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
                android:value=".SearchResultsActivity" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".SearchResultsActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable" />

        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

And finally here is my SearchActivity class:

```
package eu.mcm.prindl.magiccardmarket;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

/**
 * Created by konstantin on 8/5/15.
 */

public class SearchResultsActivity extends Activity
{
    private static final String TAG = "SearchResultsActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.search_result_layout);

        handleIntent(getIntent());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent (Intent intent)
    {
        //super.onNewIntent(intent);
        setIntent(intent);
        handleIntent(intent);
    }

    /**
     * Handling intent data
     */
    private void handleIntent (Intent intent)
    {
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction()))
        {
            String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
            Debug.write(TAG,"Search Query: " + query);

        }

    }
}
```

Please help. I have looked for various solutions on Stackoverflow but none seemed to work (but maybe I just missed some things).

UPDATE:
Here is my searchable.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    android:label="@string/app_label"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint" >
</searchable>
```

Comment: If you are using `AppCompat` you do not need this: `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)`.

Comment: Oh thanks, I've removed it but this actually doesn't change my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Your manifest should look more like the following with what it contains:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="...">
<application android:name="..." android:icon="@drawable/logo" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/...">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable" android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
        <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>
        ...
    </activity>
    ...
</application>
```

With the matching XML file containing something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/search_name" android:hint="@string/hint_search" />
```

Also make sure your Activity actually sets up the Search View:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
    if (searchView != null) {
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setOnCloseListener(new SearchView.OnCloseListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onClose() {
                //TODO: Reset your views
                return false;
            }
        });
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
                    return false; //do the default
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
                    //NOTE: doing anything here is optional, onNewIntent is the important bit
                    if (s.length() > 1) { //2 chars or more
                        //TODO: filter/return results
                    } else if (s.length() == 0) {
                        //TODO: reset the displayed data
                    }
                    return false;
                }

            });
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this actually does not seem to solve my problem. Actually my problem is that onNewIntent never gets executed.I've added my searchable.xml in the first post, but it is the same as yours.